# How to generate C# types from GraphQL schema

Tags: c#, graphql

i am new for GraphQL and i am trying to convert the graphql schema into c# classes
GraphQL:- `input Element{ id: Int name: String! }` 
C#:-

```
 class Element 
{ 
    public int id {get;set;} 
    public string name {get;set;} 
}
```

Is this possible. if yes then how, because manually creating the class is not solution in my case because i have big schema. also special paste is not working in visual studio.
Thanks

Comment: Have you looked [**at**](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet/issues/317) the Github issues/solutions on this?

Comment: If you have an xml schema the download from msdn xsd.exe which will create classes from schema.

Answer (score 1):

With "Strawberry Shake" you can generate a complete C# client out of a schema and a query:
https://chillicream.com/docs/strawberryshake/#introduction

Your question will be easier to answer when you give a few more details about your usecase. (e.g.: do your queries change at runtime? How much & how accurate do you expect the types to be?)

I can already spot a mistake in your translation: id is nullable in the schema. And you can only leverage the graphql schema safety when you include the queries in the generator. (Imagine you use that class with a query like `query { id }` - the name won't come back but it is even non-nullable in the schema!)